# Loop on each h2 tag inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="document-content" contenteditable="true">
<h2>Heading 1</h2>
<p>Content</p>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p>Content</p>
</div>
```

How do I loop on each of the `h2` tags inside that div?

The best I could do was to find only one of the `h2` tags:

```
$('.document-content').find('h2').html()
```

I need to find all so I can do stuff like adding classes or IDs to each of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each()` function:

```js
$('.document-content').find('h2').each(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  that.addClass('custom-class');
  // more code here..
  // that.find('.another-element').addClass('test');
});
```

```css
.custom-class {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="document-content" contenteditable="true">
<h2>Heading 1</h2>
<p>Content</p>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious why the need of using `that`?

Comment: Set $(this) equal to that, only if you want to use $(this) object more that once inside each function, in order to avoid creating it multiple times (in my example you can use ( $(this).addClass('class') )

Answer (score 1):

Without using the **.find()**

```js
$('.document-content>h2').each(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  that.addClass('custom-class');
});
```

```css
.custom-class {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="document-content" contenteditable="true">
  <h2>Heading 1</h2>
  <p>Content</p>
  <h2>Heading 2</h2>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to find all so I can do stuff like adding classes or IDs to each of them.

You don't even need `.each()` here, as the other answers have said. `.html()` returns the HTML content of the first element in the set. However, things like `.addClass('myClass')` will apply to *all* elements in the set. So, to add `.myClass` to them all, you could do:

```
$('.document-content h2').addClass('myClass')
```

(As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28426430/3187556), `.find()` isn't really necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

(imo) You don't need the `find()` function. You can use this (in combination with [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/))

```
$('.document-content h2').each( function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Also check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rej11k6v/)

Answer (score 0):

You need each `h2` tag in `document-content` class so you need to iterate each `h2` tag using jQuery's `.each()` function to find all `h2` tag and addClass to it.

```
$("div.document-content").find("h2").each(function(){
   $(this).addClass("your_class");
});
```